# Access_log coming with date and time

Tags: squid

I need to use access_log for some automation purpose.
After sometime access_logs are coming with date and time, i want to keep it with the name access_log only.
I have given the name in squid.conf but that is not working for me.
please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your Squid configuration file and make sure there is no [logfile_rotate](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/logfile_rotate/) parameter specified.

Then, check your operating system's logrotate.d folder for a configuration file directing it to rotate Squid's configuration file, and either remove the file completely, or rename it so it has a ".disabled" extension (may not work on all distributions).

On CentOS the logrotate configuration can be found at /etc/logrotate.d/squid.